# Modifying cookie domain in Google Tag Manager from ".example.com" to "example.com"

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

on my website I have Google Tag Manager with a GA Universal Analytics Tag installed. All images on the site are on a dedicated subdomain: images.example.com

My issue is that Analytics sets its _ga cookie to ".example.com" so it is sent along with all requests to images.example.com. I would like to set the cookie domain to "example.com" (without the dot) so it does not apply to my image-only subdomain.

I have already set the "Cookie Domain" setting to a macro which is a constant with the value "domain.com" and even though the container is properly published the cookie domain remains ".example.com"

Do you guys have any hints on how I could change the cookie domain?

Answer (score 1):

Use the cookie domain "none"

This will set a host-only cookie which will *not* be sent for all subdomains.  Except in IE.

See the localhost example here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @ruffp I take it that you haven't read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/238586

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat no I didn't and it really does not help to review such "answers" .. for me this one needs more work to be a good quality answer.

Comment: @ruffp It _may_ not necessarily be a good answer, but it definitely does not deserve deletion.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat but if it was in the low quality queue it means somebody flag it as low quality and it was my opinion as well... after if the answerer improve his answer I would not mind it stays. Anyway this site is more a matter of what is useful for people, if my opinion is not taken in account I would not mind, that's the rule.